# postgres query performance issue when getting top 10 result from sorted list

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql

Tools: Rails and Postgresql

Data structure:

Feed: has many Messages

Message: has one Author

```
messages:
  feed_id
  author_id
  posted_at
```

Author: contains a hstore

```
authors:
  account_stats->'likes_count'
```

I have a set of messages that filtered by feed_ids and posted_at timestamp.

I want to get the top 10 author ids sorted by the likes_count with in this set of messages.

Both of the author and messages set are pretty big, around 1-2M records in this set.

Initially I tried two seperate queries, find the author_ids for the messages first, then find all the authors in that author_ids, but this author_ids list is too big, so I tried to make them into one query using CTE.

Here's what I did:

`WITH "filtered_messages" AS (SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"  WHERE "messages"."feed_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 7) AND (messages.posted_at >= '2014-11-24 00:00:00.000000') AND (messages.posted_at < '2014-12-09 05:00:00.000000')) SELECT  "authors"."id_str" FROM "authors"  WHERE (authors.id_str in (select distinct filtered_messages.author_id from filtered_messages))  ORDER BY (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10`

But this query is very slow:

Here's the query plan using explain analyse
http://explain.depesz.com/s/xCg

or

```
      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=48170.47..48170.49 rows=10 width=88) (actual time=7352.169..7352.171 rows=10 loops=1)
   CTE filtered_messages
     ->  Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..37190.11 rows=414468 width=2024) (actual time=0.179..271.049 rows=416269 loops=1)
           Filter: ((posted_at >= '2014-11-24 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (posted_at < '2014-12-09 05:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (feed_id = ANY ('{1,2,3,7}'::integer[])))
           Rows Removed by Filter: 21420
   ->  Sort  (cost=10980.35..10980.85 rows=200 width=88) (actual time=7352.169..7352.171 rows=10 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (((authors.account_stats -> 'likes_count'::text))::integer)
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=9330.45..10976.03 rows=200 width=88) (actual time=1555.397..7268.009 rows=304363 loops=1)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9330.03..9332.03 rows=200 width=516) (actual time=1555.342..1610.825 rows=304363 loops=1)
                     ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=9325.53..9329.53 rows=200 width=516) (actual time=1360.939..1469.422 rows=304363 loops=1)
                           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=9325.53..9327.53 rows=200 width=516) (actual time=1360.938..1434.832 rows=304363 loops=1)
                                 ->  CTE Scan on filtered_messages  (cost=0.00..8289.36 rows=414468 width=516) (actual time=0.183..1181.150 rows=416269 loops=1)
               ->  Index Scan using authors_pkey on authors  (cost=0.42..8.20 rows=1 width=88) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=304363)
                     Index Cond: ((id_str)::text = ("ANY_subquery".author_id)::text)
 Total runtime: 7418.278 ms
```

The total runtime is very slow. I tried to add ordered index for the likes_count, but the plan did not use it. Is there any other index I should add?

`"CREATE INDEX index_authors_on_likes_count ON authors (((account_stats -> 'likes_count')::INT) DESC NULLS LAST) where (account_stats ? 'likes_count')"`

EDIT: using join table:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT "authors"."id_str", (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT FROM "authors" 
INNER JOIN "messages" ON "messages"."author_id" = "authors"."id_str" 
WHERE ( "messages"."feed_id" IN (6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7) AND (messages.posted_at >= '2014-10-26 00:00:00.000000') AND (messages.posted_at < '2015-12-11 05:00:00.000000'))  
ORDER BY (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10;
```

Two different query plan result:

with feed_ids = 1,2,3,7: explain.depesz.com/s/iaR

with feed_ids = 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 7, big date range:  explain.depesz.com/s/cGm

with feed_ids = 6,4,5,1,2,3,7, same date range: http://explain.depesz.com/s/UbPg

The query plan is about the same, but after the table size increase, the join seems to be slow. Maybe some index will help? I have index on authors.id_str and messages.author_id already.

Thanks in advance for any help and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are comparing id_Str with author_id and this field don t have same type, i m right? I supposed varchar and bigint?

postgres need to compare same type, so when you campare different type, postgres need to do cast for eacht line of your table! And if you have million, postgres do this action a million of time.

So you need to review your model by converting your id_str to bigint (same type as author_id) or try to create an index on id_str like

```
create index idx_id_str on mytable(id_str::bigint)
```

Check the syntax because very long time i do this;)

But in this exemple you create an index on id_str but in realitty index contains bigint value, so then postgres donc need to do cast for each line because index already have done the job as you ask it;)

In fact try to remove all cast you have because its very slowly;)

After please repost a new explain to see if its ok now;)

Ps: in your explain i can t see your index that you have create, so postgres decide to don t use it... You can remove it and try another one.;)

new comment:

```
WITH "filtered_messages" AS (SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"  
WHERE "messages"."feed_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 7) 
AND (messages.posted_at >= '2014-11-24 00:00:00.000000')
AND (messages.posted_at < '2014-12-09 05:00:00.000000')) 
SELECT  "authors"."id_str" FROM "authors"  
WHERE (authors.id_str in (select distinct filtered_messages.author_id from filtered_messages)) 
ORDER BY (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10
```

try to do :

```
WITH "filtered_messages" AS (SELECT distinct "messages".author_id  FROM "messages"  
WHERE "messages"."feed_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 7) 
AND (messages.posted_at >= '2014-11-24 00:00:00.000000')
AND (messages.posted_at < '2014-12-09 05:00:00.000000')) 
SELECT  "authors"."id_str" FROM "authors"  
WHERE (authors.id_str in (select filtered_messages.author_id from filtered_messages)) 
ORDER BY (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10
```

i just add distinct in you filtered_messages table to have only author_id and not all, to have a filtered_messages table that contains only the minimum of data

and then, because we already have distinct a this point, you don t need it in the where clause:

```
WHERE (authors.id_str in (select filtered_messages.author_id from filtered_messages))
```

can you try this and repost a new explain?

thanks

Comment: Thanks for replying, I learn something new. My authors.id_str and messages.author_id are both string before, but I changed both to text so it will not cast during comparison, but the result time is no different. here's new explain: [link](http://explain.depesz.com/s/PuD) or http://explain.depesz.com/s/PuD

Comment: and try to use this syntax if you can : SELECT  authors.id_str FROM authors  
join messages on messages.author_id = authors.id_str 
  AND messages.feed_id IN (1, 2, 3, 7) 
  AND (messages.posted_at >= '2014-11-24 00:00:00.000000') 
  AND (messages.posted_at < '2014-12-09 05:00:00.000000')
ORDER BY (account_stats->'likes_count')::INT DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 10  and give me the result ;)

Comment: I tried both of them, the first only selecting author_ids first does not help, the query plan did not change. With the second approach, join the two table instead of using ids IN ([]), the query plan improved a lot with this set of data. http://explain.depesz.com/s/iaR . But after I increased the feed_ids, so the messages count go up to 2M, and author count to 1M, this approach is slow again. But still much better than before. http://explain.depesz.com/s/cGm

Comment: ok, now as you can see in you explain you have "seq scan" on messages and authors. seq scan is a sequential scan, so each line of the table is read to compare with your condition. and to resolve this you need to add index on this table like create index idx_messages_authorid_feedid on messages (author_id, feed_id) and then try create index idx_messages_authorid_feedid_postedat on messages (author_id, feed_id,postedat). then try new explain to see if you have index scan instead of seq scan. then try same thing on authors table ;) try to comment your order by and try new explain;)

Comment: Do you have resolve your problem? Can you please accept my answer if it is;) thanks

Comment: sorry, I was busy these days. Ya I will accept your answer since it helper a lot. thanks. I might come back to this problem later with more improvement, and let you know if there's any progress.